# Sybase and null string in select. Weird processing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, sybase, isnull

Using Sybase ASE 15.7 ( But i think it is the same for MSSqlServer ), 
I just faced this strange behaviour :

let's say i have a very simple 2 columns table :

```
create table testtable( 
    id int identity not null,
    name varchar(50) null
)
```

Inside it, i'll insert 2 different values and null several times :

```
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL1"
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL1"
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL1"
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL1"
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL2"
insert into testtable( name ) select "VAL2"
insert into testtable( name ) select null
insert into testtable( name ) select null
```

So here is the content of my table :

```
select * from testtable
```

And i obtain :

```
1   VAL1
2   VAL1
3   VAL1
4   VAL1
5   VAL2
6   VAL2
7   NULL
8   NULL
```

Now the strange thing begin, let's say i want all the values except "VAL1" i would issue this query :

```
select * from testtable where name <> "VAL1"
```

i have the 2 VAL2 lines of course, but not the ones with null. As if null and VAL1 are equal

```
5   VAL2
6   VAL2
```

Of course, i know i should have issued this query :

```
select * from testtable where isnull( name, "" ) <> "VAL1"
```

The reason why i post here isn't that i want to find a workaround for this, (i know it very well and use it since year), it is more to understand better the way sybase "thinks" about null values and if someone may a clear explanation about the underlying logic because since years i workaround it, but still i don't really get the point.

Thanks and regards

Comment: can u check my answer

Comment: Ok i got it. since it cannot be compared to other values it isn't retrieved if i issue a search condition on that column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T-SQL` will  based on standard SQLimplements only one general purpose mark called NULL for any kind of missing value. This leads to three-valued predicate logic

Therefore, here are the three logic conditions you can have.

1 - Value matches condition

2 - Value does not match condition

3 - Value is missing.

```
SELECT * FROM #TESTTABLE WHERE NAME = 'VAL1' 

id  name
1   VAL1
2   VAL1
3   VAL1
4   VAL1

SELECT * FROM #TESTTABLE WHERE NAME <> 'VAL1' 

id  name
5   VAL2
6   VAL2

SELECT * FROM #TESTTABLE WHERE NAME = 'VAL1'  or name is null
id  name
1   VAL1
2   VAL1
3   VAL1
4   VAL1
7   NULL
8   NULL
```

NULL is an unknown value  it will neither equal or not equal a given value - that's why the IS NULL is required here.

Generally we cannot compare null values with operator we can use only `is null`